# Magento Point of Sale Integration

Tags: magento, point-of-sale

I am currently building a Magento (Community Edition) site for a customer who needs Magento to sync with their inventory software, and I am having a very hard time figuring this out.

I have searched everywhere and can not find an answer. So far the best I have found is that Magento can connect to Quickbooks using eCC. However, I have read that Quickbooks sucks and that eCC is a pretty poor program (as in, it sucks too).

The client is willing to use any POS/RMS software. i.e. Microsoft Dyanimcs, Sage, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After MUCH searching, I found a few things. Magento can export .csv files that can be imported into Quickbooks (or any other RMS/POS software). Magento can export/import these .csv files (and i think xml files) automatically with cron. And i believe that Quickbooks/Sage/Dynamics or any other RMS can automatically export/import .csv files as well.

I am still very new to this and have not implemented this solution yet, so i could be wrong on  the exact details.

Also, i think that you need an ftp server to act as the medium for the .csv files. I hope this helps anyone else who comes across this problem.

Comment: I am not happy and I assume the community will not be happy with this answer. I think an automatic solution is more elegant than a maul export and import .csv

Comment: That was written over 4 years ago Stevie... please check the dates.

Comment: Even 4 years ago, it is a poor quality answer and is of little help imo

Comment: It was the best solution 4 years ago. Also, cron jobs ARE automatic... not manual. Please look it up. As for your opinion... I could care less. Stop being a troll.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to contact the folks over at http://www.ebridgeconnections.com/.  Magento Enterprise edition claims to have the "Bridge Connect" integration.  We had a client that needed to connect with Sage Timberline, so we called Varien to see if it was possible to get the modules for that connectivity, but they said no.

After looking at an installation of EE, we didn't see any modules for this at all, so they either don't actually exist, or they are extra that you have to request for EE.

Upon actually calling eBridge, they claimed that no additional modules were needed.  But, the problem that we encountered was that they hadn't actually built the web services for that particular software yet (Timberline).

So, while I don't have a solid answer for you, I hope that perhaps this helps in some way.

Answer (score 1):

[Lightspeed by xSilve](http://lightspeedretail.com) has a magento connector, although we have had some painful problems getting it running, once it's up it's relatively handy. it connects inventory, and transfers sales back to lightspeed.